# Set google maps marker position with city name (address?)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Im creating a map with Google Maps JavaScript API V3

When Setting Marker 'Position' Property, We have to set it with latitude and longitude.

what if I want to create a Country map (center) and place markers on Cities with city name?

I have done this with Static maps, but I cant find a way to do this with javascript maps:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=660x400&sensor=false&center=malaysia&markers=kualalumpur&markers=Klang&markers=Ipoh

Any Ideas?

Comment: Use the [geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the **[Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)** to do this, all you have to do is to request :

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=PLACE&sensor=false
```

Depending of what you want in return (Json or XML), and where **PLACE** is where you want to Geocode, and where every space is replace by `+`. I advice you to give an accurate address  by adding the postal code and the country for exemple to prevent errors.

The advantage of using this is that the user don't have to request the Google Geocoding everytime you show the map, especially when you have a lot of markers. You Geocode once only.

Comment: Is there any restrictions on usage of the same?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question