# Creating Google Maps markers from cities in a database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps

I'm currently trying to build my own Google Map that will display each of the locations of where students are from, similar to one like [this](https://www.zeemaps.com/map?group=1073374). I've looked into Zeemaps, but it seems to only accept imports from a CSV file.

My first question would be whether it is possible to create a marker with just the City, State and Country (I wouldn't be able to use Zip for international students, and I want to avoid having a specific address for privacy reasons), rather than the Lat and Long. I see this example for creating the marker from W3schools

```
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);

var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:myCenter,
});
```

Is there a similar way to create a point with City, [State], Country?

And if not, are there any in-between functions from the Google Maps API that could do the conversions in another function?

Comment: Google Maps has a function where you can pass an address (City, State, Country should be sufficient) and they will return the lat/long. Because of the processing overhead its best done once as a separate operation, then use the output to populate your map markers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set google maps marker position with city name (address?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165059/set-google-maps-marker-position-with-city-name-address)

Comment: @geocodezip That link is definitely a great resource. But I think there's one more factor in this situation: since I'm going to need to do a few hundred locations, the API's request limit might become a factor. Not that it can't be used, but just that it's a little bit different than that situation. Thank you for the resource though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for Geocoding it is also from Google Maps API. I know that each city has a geolocation. and you can query for the LatLng coordinates.
When you query by `addressName` just leave out the zip it will give you the coordinates closest. Coordinates for a city may sometimes go to its central station or wherever that maybe a geographical center of that particular city.

Read [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/). maybe it will point you in the right direction

Comment: That sounds great. I think that's definitely what I was looking for to get started. My next concern is how to best deal with the API's 5-per-second request limit (and 2500 per day). Do you know if an array of locations passed to the Geocoder would count as one request... or would each location in the array have to be done in its own request?

Comment: You can implement some small application which saves the locations to a database so you fetch the data only once from the API. so your maps app can check the database array before going to the API if somethings are missing then it can fetch those. That would drastically cut down requests